# Why is the Minkowski Metric with exponent 0.5 not the same as Euclidean Distance when using Voronoi node?

Tags: texturing, procedural, shader-nodes

I am experimenting with the Voronoi Node and I find the following very strange.
I think that the Vorinoi Works by placing points in 3D space and then measuring the distance from them. There are different metrics to measure the distance, which result in different scalar values. The scalars are then getting converted into colours, for example using a colour ramp.

Now from the documentation I red that with Minkowski metric they mean that the distance is calculated using this function, which is the same as the p-norm in mathematics:
[image: p-norm]

Now I find confusing that the Minkowski Metric with p=0.5 leads to a different result than the Euclidean distance.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

While I was writing the question, I noticed that I made a dumb mistake. Of course an exponent of 0.5 leads to the wrong result! Because the euclidean metric is the p-norm with exponent 2, not 0.5.

More information about the p-norm can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions).

I am putting the question up here anyways, in case someone makes the same mistake.